# Data coming late in redux in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm consuming two APIS to get lyrics of songs and biography of the artist, and i need to store that in my reducer, the problem i have, is that, when i call the second api ( meaning, to get the biography ), and my stuff get save in my store, everything it's good except for the biography, because there appears only and empty object, let me show you

This is my code, just look at the BiographyAPI function

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { ADD } from "../actionTypes/Actions";

import {
  HomeContain,
  SearcherForm,
  SearcherContainInputs,
  SearcherInput,
  SearcherResults,
  SearcherButton,
  SearchIcon,
  SearcherContainButton,
  Loading
} from "./HomeStyled";

const Home = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [artistSong, setArtistSong] = useState({
    artist: "",
    title: "",
    biography: {},
    lyrics: ""
  });

  const [artist, setArtist] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const NotFirstTime = useRef(true);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Asking for the artists and songs

  const musicians = useSelector(state => state);

  // Asking the server for lyrics by artist and title

  const APIcall = async () => {
    try {
      if (artist && title) {
        const data = await fetch(
          `https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/${artist}/${title}`
        );

        const response = await data.json();

        setArtistSong({ ...artistSong, lyrics: response.lyrics });
        setArtist("");
        setTitle("");
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Asking the server for byography by artist name

  const BiographyAPI = async () => {
    try {
      if (artistSong.lyrics) {
        const data = await fetch(
          `https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=${artistSong.artist}`
        );

        const response = await data.json();

        setLoading(false);

        setArtistSong({ ...artistSong, biography: response.artists });
        if (artistSong.biography) {
          dispatch({ type: ADD, payload: artistSong });
        } else {
          return;
        }

        // setArtistSong({ artist: "", title: "", biography: {}, lyrics: "" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (NotFirstTime.current) {
      NotFirstTime.current = false;
      return;
    } else {
      APIcall();

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (artist && title && !artistSong.lyrics && loading) {
          setArtist("");
          setTitle("");
          setLoading(false);
          clearTimeout();
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }, 7000);
    }
  }, [artistSong]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BiographyAPI();
  }, [artistSong.lyrics]);

  // Fulling artistSong to make calls to API'S

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setArtistSong({
      ...artistSong,
      artist: artist.toLowerCase(),
      title: title.toLowerCase()
    });
    setLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <HomeContain>
        {/* The Form To Search Songs */}

        <SearcherForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <SearcherContainInputs>
            <SearcherInput
              type="text"
              name="artist"
              placeholder="Artist"
              maxLength="40"
              required
              value={artist}
              onChange={e => setArtist(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />

            <SearcherInput
              type="text"
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
              maxLength="50"
              value={title}
              required
              onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />

            <SearcherContainButton>
              <SearcherButton type="submit">
                <SearchIcon />
              </SearcherButton>
            </SearcherContainButton>
          </SearcherContainInputs>
        </SearcherForm>

        {/* Showing The Results Of The Search */}

        <SearcherResults>
          {loading && <Loading />}

          {artistSong.lyrics && artistSong.biography && (
            <>
              <h1>WE GOT IT</h1>
            </>
          )}
        </SearcherResults>
      </HomeContain>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

This is my reducer

```
import { ADD } from "../actionTypes/Actions";

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return [...state, action.payload], console.log(action.payload.biography);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

So as i wrote, the first call to the api it returns me this the biography, but in my reducer there's an empty object, it is not saving the biography stuff

[image]

what's going on and how can i fix it ?

Comment: By the time you call `dispatch` state is not yet updated (here are more details why https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state ) you need to create the object you want, dispatch to the store and to the state (or even better read it from the store, no need to duplicate it in the state, unless you have a good reason for that)

Comment: It kinda makes sense, maybe state it's not updated yet, i'll figure out how to do it right, thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Nadia's answer and her recommendations are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will solve the problem, but it is a problem too :

1. the state suppose to be an object
2. change the reducer like this:

```
    case ADD:
      {
        console.log(action.payload);
        return ... (object!!);
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure the state should be an object? i didn't know that, i've seen many apps and courses where state it's an arrayy, but i'll try that out, an thankf for aswering me !

Comment: It is not must but usually you store in the state different values that not related to each other, so array is not the appropriate data type for that purpose.

Comment: The state can be any type.  Some "counter" examples just use a `number` as the entire state. An `object` is definitely the most common.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this, state in redux is object

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, i'll try that out !

Answer (score 1):

You aren't really using Redux at all right now.  The only data that you select from the store is unused.  You can actually handle all of your API calls by dispatching actions.  You can use Redux to access the `loading` and `artistSong` states.  Your component becomes a lot simpler and your Redux store becomes a lot more complex.

reducer & actions:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchLyrics = createAsyncThunk(
  "song/fetchLyrics",
  async ({ artist, title }) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/${artist}/${title}`
    );

    const json = await response.json();

    return json.lyrics;
  }
);

export const fetchBiography = createAsyncThunk(
  "song/fetchBiography",
  async ({ artist }) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=${artist}`
    );

    const json = await response.json();

    // returns an array but we only want the first entry
    return json.artists[0] || {};
  }
);

const initialState = {
  artist: "",
  title: "",
  biography: {},
  lyrics: "",
  isLoadingLyrics: false,
  isLoadingBio: false
};

const songSlice = createSlice({
  name: "song",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchLyrics.pending](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingLyrics = true;
      // argument passed the function
      const { artist, title } = action.meta.arg;
      state.artist = artist;
      state.title = title;
    },
    [fetchLyrics.rejected](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingLyrics = false;
    },
    [fetchLyrics.fulfilled](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingLyrics = false;
      state.lyrics = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchBiography.pending](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingBio = true;
    },
    [fetchBiography.rejected](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingBio = false;
    },
    [fetchBiography.fulfilled](state, action) {
      state.isLoadingBio = false;
      state.biography = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export default songSlice.reducer;
```

store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import song from "./song";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    song
    // can combine with other reducers
  }
});

export default store;
```

component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Asking for the artists and songs

  const song = useSelector((state) => state.song);

  const { isLoadingLyrics, isLoadingBio } = song;

  // Dispatching actions to make calls to APIs

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // don't re-fetch same data
    if (artist && artist !== song.artist) {
      dispatch(fetchBiography({ artist }));
    }

    if (artist && song && !(artist === song.artist && title === song.title)) {
      dispatch(fetchLyrics({ artist, title }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <HomeContain>
        {/* The Form To Search Songs */}

        <SearcherForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <SearcherContainInputs>
            <SearcherInput
              type="text"
              name="artist"
              placeholder="Artist"
              maxLength="40"
              required
              value={artist}
              onChange={(e) => setArtist(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />

            <SearcherInput
              type="text"
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
              maxLength="50"
              value={title}
              required
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
            />

            <SearcherContainButton>
              <SearcherButton type="submit">
                <SearchIcon />
              </SearcherButton>
            </SearcherContainButton>
          </SearcherContainInputs>
        </SearcherForm>

        {/* Showing The Results Of The Search */}

        <SearcherResults>
          {isLoadingLyrics ? <Loading /> : <p>{song.lyrics}</p>}
          {isLoadingBio ? (
            <Loading />
          ) : (
            <div>
              <h2>{song.biography.strArtist || song.artist}</h2>
              <p>{song.biography.strBiographyEN}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </SearcherResults>
      </HomeContain>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```